# Why is data.table casting column classes when I assign all columns by reference

Tags: r, data.table

Here is something I do not understand with `data.table`
If I select a line and I try to set all values of this line to `NA` the new line-data.table is coerced to logical

```
#Here is a sample table
DT <- data.table(a=rep(1L,3),b=rep(1.1,3),d=rep('aa',3))
DT
#    a   b  d
# 1: 1 1.1 aa
# 2: 1 1.1 aa
# 3: 1 1.1 aa

#Here I extract a line, all the column types are kept... good
str(DT[1])
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  1 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ a: int 1
#  $ b: num 1.1
#  $ d: chr "aa"
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 

#Now here I want to set them all to `NA`...they all become logicals => WHY IS THAT ?
str(DT[1][,colnames(DT) := NA])
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  1 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ a: logi NA
#  $ b: logi NA
#  $ d: logi NA
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

EDIT: I think it is a bug as

```
str(DT[1][ , a := NA])
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  1 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ a: logi NA
#  $ b: num 1.1
#  $ d: chr "aa"
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 

str(DT[1:2][ , a := NA])
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ a: int  NA NA
#  $ b: num  1.1 1.1
#  $ d: chr  "aa" "aa"
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: I see now what you meant, according to me data.table is supposed to keep the LHS type of the column, so whatever the RHS is shouldn't matter, worst case scenario I should get a warning message and never get a cast like this (I think...)

Comment: @Arun I thought the package always said it "plonked" a column when a full overwrite was done (as long as `verbose` is toggled on) to tell the user that the column class might have changed, but I don't see it here...? It doesn't say anything if the vector is recycled, then?

Comment: Yes @Frank has it. It's _plonk_ feature. Search `?":="` for "plonk" (long paragraph there). I don't think it's a bug, iiuc.

Comment: What does plonk mean? I saw it in the help but skipped it

Comment: @MatthewDowle, iiuc when RHS_SXP > LHS_SXP, there's a warning... Ex: LHS is logical and RHS is integer. But the other way doesn't. About right?

Comment: @Arun Exactly, when coercing to a lower type there might be loss of data (hence warning) but no need when coercing up. There's a FR to not warn when the RHS is a singleton (the cost of checking whether data would be lost is so low for 1 item) since that's a common case e.g. DT[i,col:=1] where col is type integer but the single 1 is type double in R.

Comment: So could somebody explain why a 2 rows data.table has a different behaviour than a 1 row data.table ? May be as an answer so we can close cause I still do not get it

Comment: @statquant I'm not confident enough to make this an answer, but I think the warning is given for `DT[1:2][,a:=1]` and not `DT[1:2][,a:=c(1,2)]` because the second version suggests that you realize that you're overwriting the whole column, while maybe the recycling in the first version was accidental...The doc says "Changing a column type is possible but deliberately harder: provide a whole column as the RHS."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To provide an answer, from `?":="` :

> Unlike `<-` for `data.frame`, the (potentially large) LHS is not coerced to match the type of the (often small) RHS. Instead the RHS is coerced to match the type of the LHS, if necessary. Where this involves double precision values being coerced to an integer column, a warning is given (whether or not fractional data is truncated). The motivation for this is efficiency. It is best to get the column types correct up front and stick to them. **Changing a column type is possible but deliberately harder: provide a whole column as the RHS.** This RHS is then plonked into that column slot and we call this plonk syntax, or replace column syntax if you prefer. **By needing to construct a full length vector of a new type**, you as the user are more aware of what is happening, and it's clearer to readers of your code that you really do intend to change the column type.

The motivation for all this is large tables (say 10GB in RAM), of course. Not 1 or 2 row tables.

To put it more simply:  if `length(RHS) == nrow(DT)` then the RHS (and whatever its type) is *plonked* into that column slot.  Even if those lengths are 1.  If `length(RHS) < nrow(DT)`, the memory for the column (and its type) is kept in place, but the RHS is coerced and recycled to *replace* the (subset of) items in that column.

If I need to change a column's type in a large table I write:

```
DT[, col := as.numeric(col)]
```

here `as.numeric` allocates a new vector, coerces "col" into that new memory, which is then plonked into the column slot.  It's as efficient as it can be.  The reason that's a plonk is because `length(RHS) == nrow(DT)`.

If you want to overwrite a column with a different type containing some default value:

```
DT[, col := rep(21.5, nrow(DT))]    # i.e., deliberately harder
```

If "col" was type integer before, then it'll change to type numeric containing 21.5 for every row. Otherwise just `DT[, col := 21.5]` would result in a warning about 21.5 being coerced to 21 (unless DT is only 1 row!)