# How to create a data.table with one row filled with NA based on another data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Say I have the following `data.table` (but think of it as a table with a lot of columns with dynamically changing names)

```
DT <- data.table(a=rep(1L,3),b=rep(1.32,3),d=rep("qwe",3))
DT
   a    b   d
1: 1 1.32 qwe
2: 1 1.32 qwe
3: 1 1.32 qwe
```

Say now that I want to create a row with `NAs` that I could then `rbindlist` with DT.

First try (it is not working)

```
DT1 <- DT[1][,colnames(DT):=NA]
DT1
    a  b  d
1: NA NA NA
rbindlist(list(DT1,DT))
      a    b  d
1:   NA   NA NA
2: TRUE TRUE NA
3: TRUE TRUE NA
4: TRUE TRUE NA
```

This is not working because `DT1` is casted when `:=NA` is called (something called plonking it seems, because if you provide a full column when `:=` RHS type will overwrite LHS...)

The question is then, how can I extract a row of a `data.table` and fill it with NA or create a `data.table`, filled with NA that have the same column names and column type that another

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many ways of doing it, here's one:

```
rbind(DT[NA], DT)
#    a    b   d
#1: NA   NA  NA
#2:  1 1.32 qwe
#3:  1 1.32 qwe
#4:  1 1.32 qwe
```

Comment: +1 you might also have some insight into @statquant's [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18594017/1478381)

Comment: Good stuff @eddi did not know this way of constructing a one row `DT` ! Feel free to edit the wiki http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=packages:cran:data.table

Comment: +1  And `DT[0]` is the way to create an empty table instead (with all the same column names and types). @statquant `DT[NA]` is buried in FAQ 2.17.

Comment: @MatthewDowle, In fact I knew about `DT[0]` I think I tried `DT[0], DT[-1],DT[NULL]` but not `DT[NA]` :(

Comment: And to add 5 rows of  `NA`s you could use `rbind(DT[NA][1:5], DT)`.