# Does data.table's `:=` operator really operate by reference?

Tags: r, data.table

data.table's `:=` operator is [documented as](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.13.0/topics/%3A%3D):

> ... adds or updates or removes
> column(s) by reference. It makes no copies of any part of memory at
> all.

So what happens here?

```
dt <- data.table(a = 1:5, b = 6:10)
address(dt$b)
# [1] "0000021cca78db58"

dt[, b := 2*a]
address(dt$b)
# [1] "0000021cc77ade10"
```

How come the address of `b` column changes?

I'm using R 3.6.1 and data.table 1.12.8.

Comment: Try `dt[a == 3, b := 2 * a]`; `address(dt$b)` -> -> I think this is a related issue: [`:=` does not update by reference existing column if `i` is missing](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3908)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You (or perhaps the column) just got *plonked* ;) The plonk behaviour is rather thoroughly described in the help text (`` ?`:=` ``):

> Unlike `<-` for `data.frame`, the (potentially large) LHS is not coerced to match the type of the (often small) RHS. Instead the RHS is coerced to match the type of the LHS, if necessary. Where this involves double precision values being coerced to an integer column, a warning is given (whether or not fractional data is truncated). The motivation for this is efficiency. It is best to get the column types correct up front and stick to them. Changing a column type is possible but deliberately harder: provide a whole column as the RHS. This RHS is then plonked into that column slot and we call this plonk syntax, or replace column syntax if you prefer. By needing to construct a full length vector of a new type, you as the user are more aware of what is happening, and it's clearer to readers of your code that you really do intend to change the column type.

However, the relationship between plonking and *memory* is currently *not explicitly addressed* in the docs (but see below). Hence questions like yours and by others (on github: [:= does not update by reference existing column if i is missing](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3908), [`:=` doesn't always assign in-place](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1248)).

There are a lot of interesting points in the github posts, but rather than me reiterating them, please just go there and enjoy! One [quote from Matt Dowle](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1248#issuecomment-127942621) though, which I believe nicely justifies the plonk behaviour:

> Instead of 5 column allocatons, there's just one now for the `a+a` expression (the RHS, which gets created anyway) which is then plonked into the column slot by reference i.e. `address(DT)` doesn't change but `address(DT$a)` will change. That's correct behaviour, and most efficient, to save copying the whole RHS into the existing column (which is only possible if they're the same type anyway). Since the RHS is as long as the number of rows, it is just plonked in.

(Disclaimer: things may have changed in both `data.table` and `R` since that post, but I think the main message is still valid.)

---

Regarding documentation, there is an open PR ([update and clarify := docs](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4481/)), where a more explicit description of plonk and memory is suggested:

> When a column is *plonked*, the original column is not updated by reference, because that needs to update every single element of that column.

---

Have I been plonked? Yes! For me it wasn't memory, but column classes which caused some head scratching, and I ended up here: [Why is data.table casting column classes when I assign all columns by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594017/why-is-data-table-casting-column-classes-when-i-assign-all-columns-by-reference). After reading your question, I returned to that post and realized that [the very nice answer by Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594017/why-is-data-table-casting-column-classes-when-i-assign-all-columns-by-reference) not "only" addresses class but also memory. I think it's worth repeating here (my **bold** and comment in `[]`):

> if `length(RHS) == nrow(DT)` then the RHS (and whatever its type) is
> *plonked* into that column slot.  Even if those lengths are 1.  If `length(RHS) < nrow(DT)`, the memory for the column (and its type) is
> kept in place [implicitly memory *not* kept in place when `length(RHS) == nrow(DT)`, I assume] but the RHS is coerced and recycled to *replace* the (subset of) items in that column.
>
> If I need to change a column's type in a large table I write:
>
> ```
> DT[, col := as.numeric(col)]
> ```
>
> here **`as.numeric` allocates a new vector, coerces "col" into that
> new memory, which is then plonked into the column slot**.  It's as
> efficient as it can be.  The reason that's a plonk is because
> `length(RHS) == nrow(DT)`.